# How to trickle down order by and limit in oracle views

Tags: oracle, query-performance, oracle-19c

I have oracle standard edition 2 v19 and we imitating partitions on huge tables using view with union all.
all in  all it is working well. until we need to sort.

I would like to know if there is an option to "trickle down" the sort and limit to each table instead of merging the tables and then sort + limit. Of course there is index with covering on the sort column.

Here is an example, in very large tables there is significant differences (seconds vs minutes):

DDL:

```
create table bank_p1(
userid number,
amount number(10,5),
ddate  date);

create index IX_BF_1_TM_DDATE on bank_p1(userid, ddate desc) ;


create table bank_p2(
userid number,
amount number(10,5),
ddate  date);

create index IX_BF_2_TM_DDATE on bank_p2(userid, ddate desc) ;

create view bank
(userid, amount, ddate)
as
SELECT userid, amount, ddate
FROM bank_p1
UNION ALL 
SELECT userid, amount, ddate
FROM bank_p2
;
```

Slow SQL:

```
explain plan for
SELECT userid, amount, ddate
from bank
WHERE  userid = 123456
ORDER BY ddate  desc 
offset 0 rows fetch next 500 rows only;

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                  | Name                                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                           |                                        |   500 | 28500 |  1760   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                                      |                                        |   500 | 28500 |  1760   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK                  |                                        |  3038 |   103K|  1760   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    VIEW                                    | bank                                   |  3038 |   103K|  1759   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     UNION-ALL                              |                                        |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| bank_p1                                |  2970 | 68310 |  1705   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | IX_BF_1_TM_DDATE                       |  2970 |       |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |      MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| bank_p2                                |    68 |  1496 |    54   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | IX_BF_2_TM_DDATE                       |    68 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=500 AND "from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber">0)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY INTERNAL_FUNCTION("ddate") DESC )<=500)
   6 - access("userid"=123456)
   8 - access("userid"=123456)
```

Fast SQL:

```
explain plan for
SELECT userid, amount, ddate
FROM 
( (
SELECT userid, amount, ddate
FROM bank_p1
WHERE  userid = 123456
ORDER BY ddate  desc 
offset 0 rows fetch next 500 rows only 
) UNION ALL (
SELECT userid, amount, ddate
FROM bank_p2
WHERE  userid = 123456
ORDER BY ddate  desc 
offset 0 rows fetch next 500 rows only 
))
WHERE  userid = 123456
ORDER BY ddate  desc 
offset 0 rows fetch next 500 rows only ;
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name                                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                                        |   500 | 28500 |  1762   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                                 |                                        |   500 | 28500 |  1762   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK             |                                        |  1000 | 35000 |  1762   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    VIEW                               |                                        |  1000 | 35000 |  1761   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     UNION-ALL                         |                                        |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      SORT ORDER BY                    |                                        |   500 | 28500 |  1706   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       VIEW                            |                                        |   500 | 28500 |  1705   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |        WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY          |                                        |  2970 | 68310 |  1705   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |         MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| bank_p1                                |  2970 | 68310 |  1705   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IX_BF_1_TM_DDATE                       |  2970 |       |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |      SORT ORDER BY                    |                                        |   500 | 28500 |    55   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |       VIEW                            |                                        |   500 | 28500 |    54   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |        WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY          |                                        |    68 |  1496 |    54   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |         MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| bank_p2                                |    68 |  1496 |    54   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IX_BF_2_TM_DDATE                       |    68 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_006"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=500 AND "from$_subquery$_006"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber">0)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY INTERNAL_FUNCTION("ddate") DESC )<=500)
   6 - filter("from$_subquery$_003"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=500 AND "from$_subquery$_003"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber">0)
   7 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SYS_OP_DESCEND("ddate"))<=500)
   9 - access("userid"=123456)
  11 - filter("from$_subquery$_005"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=500 AND "from$_subquery$_005"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber">0)
  12 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SYS_OP_DESCEND("ddate"))<=500)
  14 - access("userid"=123456)
```

Comment: Don't use views in your queries.  Views are meant for users that don't know the database structure.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid complex code.

Comment: Your users will enjoy the simple code and the lack of performance.

Comment: of course performance comes first. and will force it if needed. this question is if there is a better way than long `UNION ALL` sql.

Comment: You said the union all was fast?  Did you try having a single partitioned table?  Perhaps Oracle's partitions are more performant than an imitation?